# How to draw a circuit diagram to check a 4 bits number is odd or even

Tags: draw, diagram, circuit, circuit-diagram

Like the title, anyone know how to draw a circuit diagram to check a 4 bits number odd or even ??

Comment: Are you determining the evenness of the whole number, or each bit?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about digital electronics

Comment: I want to check for the whole number.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a circuit for this - bit 0 of the input determines whether the number is odd or even, so you can ignore bits 1 - 3 and just use bit 0 as an odd/even output (it will be 1 for odd, 0 for even). So the circuit, such as it is, would look like this:

```
INPUT                                        OUTPUT

bit 3 o------------- N/C

bit 2 o------------- N/C

bit 1 o------------- N/C

bit 0 o------------------------------------o odd/even
```

Comment: Thank for your useful answer, but i want to know how to draw a circuit , plz help.

Comment: OK - I've drawn the circuit, such as it is, but as you can see it almost too trivial to be worthwhile.

Comment: thx u very much, but acctually i want a circuit with digital gates for this. If u know how, i would much appreciate.

Comment: Well it doesn't actually need any gates, so that would be pointless. Are you sure you copied and pasted the homework question properly ? Perhaps you are supposed to design a circuit for odd/even *parity* ?